# Align div to start at the center of row

Tags: html, css, alignment

My intention is this:

[image: intention_desc]

Sadly I cannot figure out how to align this the way I want to, other than with margin.
The issue is with the row with button.
I want to align the div with id="info" to start at the center of the row (id="row").

This is the current state and the code, below.
[image: current_state]

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center" id="row">

    <div class="radio-btn">
        
    </div>

    <div style="margin-left: 2em; margin-right: 2em; width: 50px;">
        <img src='xy.png' style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
    </div>

    <div id="info">

        <div> SAMPLE TEXT </div>
        <div><button>SELECT PICKUP</button></div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Since I am trying to generate multiple lines like this in a for loop, I do not want to complicate things with if / else statements.

Is there a different way to achieve this, some kind of align option I am not aware of?
Or should I just use margin for the rows with buttons?

Comment: I think the only way to do this would be to absolutely position the button relative to the info div using top 100% so it appears at the bottom of the info div without affecting the alignment of the text.  However if you did this, the button wouldn't take up any space as it is outside the flow so you would need to add an extra class to containers that had a button so you could add extra bottom margin in case the button overflowed.

Comment: Protip: Don't use inline styles. No one likes to try and rectify your stylesheet with your markup. Use custom classes and keep styles together.

Comment: What CSS/library are you using? How about using a grid with the third item at top: 50% of its cell?

Comment: @isherwood You mean do not use d-flex, etc? I started using it once I started using bootstrap. I use custom classes, but when I want to just define d-flex flex-row, it is faster for me.

Comment: @AHaworth Bootstrap. That is a good idea, never used grid before, but I will check it out, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code for your question. You can add just a few css for this.

The screenshot of the result:

[image]

Check the full code below. I used **`SVG`** instead of **`img`** since it doesn't work in the current code.

```css
#row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

#info {
  position: relative;
}

#info>div:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-center" id="row">

  <div class="radio-btn">
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 2em; margin-right: 2em; width: 50px;">
    <svg class="Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"><path d="M0 0h512v512H0z" fill="#000" fill-opacity="1"></path><g class="" transform="translate(0,0)" style=""><path d="M256 24.585L51.47 118.989 256 213.394l204.53-94.405zM38.998 133.054v258.353L247 487.415V229.063zm434.004 0L265 229.062v258.353l208.002-96.008z" fill="#fff" fill-opacity="1"></path></g></svg>
  </div>

  <div id="info">
    <div> SAMPLE TEXT </div>
    <div><button>SELECT PICKUP</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Love to help you.  : ) Is this the answer to your question?

Comment: Please just one more question, what would be the best way so that the next element does not interfere with the button? 

Is it just fixed width of the id="row" div? Or is there a better way, something like fit-content that would work with the position relative / absolute you used?

Comment: The button div element has property of `position: absolute;`. so the button width doesn't affect the parent element width. You may need to use `width: -webkit-fill-available;` in the `id="info"` div element to avoid interfere.

Comment: that did not seem to work well, it made the image smaller, which i fixed with `min-width`, but the element below is still in the same place. I mean I can fix it with margin for the entire row element, but then the space would be too big for the `id="row"` elements with no button.

Comment: Are you able to share more code? I don't think that I did understand your question.

Comment: My appologies, fixed the issue, there was a parent element issue involved. Now it is alright even without the fix you suggested. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Bootstrap provides classes for more than half of the CSS rules up there. They should be used before custom CSS is written.

Comment: Glad to hear that you fixed the issue. I am very happy if my answer helps you somehow.  : )
I am ready to help you anytime.

Answer (score 1):

You could use grid. Make a grid as a "card" to insert in a container.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

#div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

#div3 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

#div4 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div id="div1">
      <input type="radio" id="radio" value="HTML">
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
      <svg id="logo-84" width="40" height="28" viewBox="0 0 40 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path class="ccustom" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9.98578 4.11462L0 14C1.99734 15.9773 4.27899 17.6437 6.76664 18.9474C7.45424 20.753 8.53203 22.4463 10 23.8995C15.5229 29.3668 24.4772 29.3668 30 23.8995C31.468 22.4463 32.5458 20.753 33.2334 18.9473C35.721 17.6437 38.0027 15.9773 40 14L30.0223 4.12266C30.0149 4.11527 30.0075 4.10788 30 4.1005C24.4772 -1.36683 15.5229 -1.36683 10 4.1005C9.99527 4.10521 9.99052 4.10991 9.98578 4.11462ZM29.0445 20.7309C26.1345 21.7031 23.0797 22.201 20 22.201C16.9203 22.201 13.8656 21.7031 10.9556 20.7309C11.2709 21.145 11.619 21.5424 12 21.9196C16.4183 26.2935 23.5817 26.2935 28 21.9196C28.381 21.5424 28.7292 21.145 29.0445 20.7309ZM12.2051 5.8824C12.9554 6.37311 13.7532 6.79302 14.588 7.13536C16.3038 7.83892 18.1428 8.20104 20 8.20104C21.8572 8.20104 23.6962 7.83892 25.412 7.13536C26.2468 6.79302 27.0446 6.3731 27.795 5.88238C23.4318 1.77253 16.5682 1.77254 12.2051 5.8824Z" fill="#3B4158"></path></svg>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
      SAMPLE TEXT
    </div>
    <div id="div4">
      <button>SELECT PICKUP</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the grid has 2 rows and 3 cols.

First div is taking the 2 rows and 1rst col. Second div is taking 2 rows and 2 col. 3rd div taking first row on 3rd col. 4th div 2nd row 3rd col.

Each div is align-self and justify-self center, in case you prefer to change positioning on a div. If you want like this, you can align and justify directly in card grid definition.

You can change names, and put divs from id to class if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, did not use grid at all yet, I will check it out, thx for the advice.